# Rewrite rule on multiple variables changing script src Path

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am using a Rewrite rule for my site but its changing changing script src Path

here is the rule i am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user_page.php?id=$1 [NC]

# Changing Search URL
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ search_out.php?comp_city=$1&one=$2comp_landmark=$3 [L]
```

# Changing Search URL is the one which is causing prob ... 
 page it will show u the script src or all link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" are pointed to http://www.xxxxx.com/Rajpura/Schools/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js rather than http://www.xxxxx.com/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the base tag to the head tag in each of your pages :

```
<base href="/">
```

This way, the browser will prepend all the links in that page by /.

For more informations about the base tag, [see documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: How is this different from what is said?

Answer (score 0):

And when embedding CSS or images in your html, try to begin with a slash to get the files from the root directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

The same with images:

```
<img src="/images/pic.png" alt="image" />
<img src="/mypic.png" alt="image" />
```

Or a Workaround would be is to add this in your template :

```
<base href="/">
```

This will force browsers to prepend the / (in this example) to all relative resource links.

Comment: Thx But is there any other way out ?? by doing changes in .htaccess... thx

Comment: no RewriteBase will not work (because it is not like that how it works). you can write a rule to redirect anything that contains (for example) js/ to /js/, but I don't suggest you to do that, the best way is adding the <base href="/" /> tag to your pages

Comment: @Yazmat Thx But almost all my links are  src=".. not  src="/ so is there any other way i can do that ?? if possible ...

Comment: @Harinder : you add the base tag only once per page in the head tag, not for every src or href

Comment: @Yazmat Thx Man it worked ... can you make it an answer so i can accept and close the question ....;)